# Find number of values for $e \in \mathbb Z$ such that $\gcd(e, 10000) = 1$, where $1<e<10000$

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, gcd-and-lcm

I need to the number of values of $e \in \mathbb Z$ such that $\gcd(e, 10000) = 1$, where $1<e<10000$.

I have no idea where to even start.

Comment: Are you familiar with the totient function?

Comment: Are you really supposed to find all the values or merely the number of such values?

Comment: @JohnLou No im not

Comment: @Randall yes I only need the number of such values

Comment: $e$ must be relatively prime to $10000$. Euler's totient function finds the number of numbers that are relatively prime to a given value.

Comment: After John Lou's comments, have you gone to Wikpedia and looked up the totient function?  Have you searched on the term in your favorite search engine?  Have you tried for some small numbers instead of $10000$ by hand?

Answer (score 2):

The prime factorization of $10{,}000$ is $2^4*5^4$. So, if we consider the $10{,}000$ integers between $1$ and $10{,}000$ inclusively then we will want to remove all integers that have either a $2$ or a $5$ in their prime factorizations.

So, start with the $10{,}000$ integers. Remove half (the even integers in that range) and then remove $1/5$ of the remaining integers (remove those with $5$ as a factor).

This yields $10{,}000 \cdot (1-\frac{1}{2}) \cdot (1-\frac{1}{5}) = 4,000$ integers in $\{1, \cdots , 10{,}000\}$ that are relatively prime to $10{,}000$.

Edit: We do not want to include $1$ for a possibility of $e$ and so we remove this one possibility. This yields $4{,}000 - 1 = 3{,}999$ such integers.